# Template load fails while moving between ui-breadrumb states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using **uiBreadcrumbs** and **$stateProvider** for moving between three states of my single page application.

Lets say these states are as

> HOME->FLOORS->FLOOR

I am able to move between these states. But when in **HOME** view onClick of some element I move to **FLOOR** view, FLOOR view comes correctly, now when i come back again on HOME view and do a same click to go again to the FLOOR view, then this time it fails to load the partial. In the FLOOR view controller I have below code:

```
document.getElementById("singleFloor");
```

This "singleFloor" element is in the HTML of template of FLOOR view.

In first move from HOME->FLOOR it can find element on loaded partial but in second time it comes as null. My state config code is as below:

```
var dashboard = angular.module('dashboardApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngResource',
    'ngAnimate',
    'angularUtils.directives.uiBreadcrumbs'
]);

dashboard.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

     $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: "/",
      views: {
        'content@': {
          templateUrl: 'partials/map.html',
          controller: 'MapController',
        }
      },
      data: {
          displayName: 'USA'
      }
    })
    .state('home.floors', {
    url: "/locations/:loc_guid/floors",
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/factoryLayout.html',
                controller: 'factoryController',
            }
        },
        data: {
            displayName: '{{location_name}}'
        },
        resolve: {
            location_name: function($state, $stateParams) {
              return $state.params.loc_name;
            }
          }
    })  
    .state('home.floors.floor', {
    url: "/:floor_guid",
        views: {
            'content@': {
                templateUrl: 'partials/floorLayout.html',
                controller: 'floorController',
            }
        },
        data: {
            displayName: '{{floor_name}}'
        },
        resolve: {
            floor_name: function($state, $stateParams) {
              return $state.params.floor_name;
            }
          }
    })  
}]);
```

So in summary in first move from HOME->FLOOR the code can find that element but in second time for same move it comes as null.

Below is the code what i am using to move from state HOME to FLOOR, this code is called onClick of some element in HOME view.

```
$state.params.floor_name = splitted_url[splitted_url.length - 3];
$state.params.loc_name = $scope.locationData.locName;
//  $state.params.loc_guid = $scope.locationData.locGUID;
// $state.params.floor_guid = splitted_url[splitted_url.length - 3];

$state.go('home.floors.floor', {
    loc_guid: $scope.locationData.locGUID,
    floor_guid: splitted_url[splitted_url.length - 3]
});
```

I have tried using $templateCache but could not get any success, I have seen in network tab of developer options that the template 'partials/floorLayout.html' is still there but not sure why in second time its not getting loaded in DOM.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces problem. Not sure why you ever need to find dom elements for navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller loads before the template so to synchronize it you can create a directive written after the template ensuring that it loads after the template and in the controller of the directive write your document.getElementById() code.....

Comment: Thanks Prashant for your advice, anyway I had solved this problem long back in similar way as you told. Cheers :)